# Python and pandas: How to use df.loc to make a new column based on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*see edits below

I have a dataframe that contains 6 columns and I am using pandas and numpy to edit and work with the data.

```
id      calv1      calv2      calv3      calv4 
1  2006-08-29 2007-08-29 2008-08-29 2009-08-29
2         NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT         
3  2006-08-29        NaT        NaT        NaT
4  2006-08-29 2007-08-29 2010-08-29        NaT
5  2006-08-29 2013-08-29        NaT        NaT
```

I want to create another column that counts the number of "calv" that occur for each id.

```
id      calv1      calv2      calv3      calv4 no_calv
1  2006-08-29 2007-08-29 2008-08-29 2009-08-29       4
2         NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT       0 
3  2006-08-29        NaT        NaT        NaT       1
4  2006-08-29 2007-08-29 2010-08-29        NaT       3
5  2006-08-29 2013-08-29        NaT        NaT       2
```

Here is my last attempt:

```
nat = np.datetime64('NaT')

df.loc[
(df["calv1"] == nat) & (df["calv2"] == nat) &
(df["calv3"] == nat) & (df["calv4"] == nat),
"no_calv"] = 0
#1 calvings
df.loc[
(df["calv1"] != nat) & (df["calv2"] == nat) &
(df["calv3"] == nat) & (df["calv4"] == nat),
"no_calv"] = 1
#2 calvings
df.loc[
(df["calv1"] != nat) & (df["calv2"] != nat) &
(df["calv3"] == nat) & (df["calv4"] == nat),
"no_calv"] = 2
#3 calvings
df.loc[
(df["calv1"] != nat) & (df["calv2"] != nat) &
(df["calv3"] != nat) & (df["calv4"] == nat),
"no_calv"] = 3
#4 or more calvings
df.loc[
(df["calv1"] != nat) & (df["calv2"] != nat) &
(df["calv3"] != nat) & (df["calv4"] != nat),
"no_calv"] = 4
```

But the result is that the whole "no_calv" column is **4.0**

I previously tried things like

```
..
(df["calv1"] != "NaT")
..
```

And

```
..
(df["calv1"] != pd.nat)
..
```

And the result was always **4.0** for the whole column or just **NaN.**

Any tips and tricks for a new python user?

*Edit:
I got a great answer for just counting the sum but I realize now that I also want to take into an account if there are missing values in between other values (see row 6):

```
id      calv1      calv2      calv3      calv4 no_calv
1  2006-08-29 2007-08-29 2008-08-29 2009-08-29       4
2         NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT       0 
3  2006-08-29        NaT        NaT        NaT       1
4  2006-08-29 2007-08-29 2010-08-29        NaT       3
5  2006-08-29 2013-08-29        NaT        NaT       2
6  2006-08-29        NaT 2013-08-29 2013-08-292     NaN #or some other value
```

This is why I was trying to be very clear with the criteria in my original example.

Comment: Just commenting to let you know, since this is an already answered question, you will probably get more attention/help if you make a new question with the additional information ('take into account if there're missing values in between') included from the getgo.

Comment: @dm2 Thank you very much for your help. Still figuring out the best way to use this great website. Should I delete this question since I've posted again and it's so similar?

Comment: I don't think there's any need to delete it. Yes, it's similar, but the additional requirement came up after it was marked as answered, and that changed the nature of the question (and in turn made the answers useful for the original question, but not for updated one). I am too still figuring this out, but you could ask in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ what's the best course of action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long the values are datetime (and NaT are missing values, not string), you can use:

```
df['no_calv'] = df.notna().sum(axis = 1)
```

To get:

```
id      calv1      calv2      calv3      calv4 no_calv
1  2006-08-29 2007-08-29 2008-08-29 2009-08-29       4
2         NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT       0 
3  2006-08-29        NaT        NaT        NaT       1
4  2006-08-29 2007-08-29 2010-08-29        NaT       3
5  2006-08-29 2013-08-29        NaT        NaT       2
```

It checks for non-missing values and sums it up along the rows (axis = 1)

Comment: Prefer `notna` rather than `~isna`. +1

Comment: Good spot, I'm too used to `isna`, gonna add an edit @Corralien

Comment: Great, I'll try this. But what if there were more columns in the dataframe the I would want to exclude from this count ?

Comment: @Thordis you'd need to specify which columns to use or which columns to ignore. Assuming we're only interested in calv1 and calv2; selecting which ones to use: `df['no_calv'] = df[['calv1','calv2']].notna().sum(axis = 1)` ; selecting which ones to ignore: `df['no_calv'] = df.drop(['calv3','calv4'], axis = 1).notna().sum(axis = 1)`

Comment: @dm2 Another issue I didn't account for my example!! What if I want to take into account that the order of the calv1,calv2,calv3,calv4 has to be specific.
As in... I don't want to count 3 if the value for calv1 is missing but values for calv2,calv3 and calv4 are there?
Then I would want a NaN or some other type to tell me the row is not correct.
That's why I was trying to specify the criteria in my original example.

Comment: @Thordis what do you mean by order being specific? The sum will be performed across the row, whether columns are cavl1,calv2,cavl3,calv4 or calv1,calv4,cavl3,calv2, the results will be the same.

Comment: @dm2 Sorry, my comment posted to soon. I have edited it to clarify my meaning.

Comment: I'm not sure if this code would be applicable or best approach in that case. I think you might need to submit a new question specifying this condition @Thordis

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `apply`:

```
 def counting_fun(row):
     return len(row.dropna()) # what is the cnt of not pd.nat columns

 df['no_calv'] = df.apply(counting_fun, axis=1)
```